# My c++ program return a weird output

Tags: c++

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  
int main()
{
    int num=0;
    cout << 'nDigits=' << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output i'm getting is: `17692393570`. Does anybody know why is this happening?. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Change `'nDigits='` to `"nDigits="`

Comment: dah! thank you very much!!!

Comment: well, I using python string style. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'nDigits='` is a multi-character character constant.

When it is written in hex using ASCII code, it becomes `6E 44 69 67 69 74 73 3D`, and `1769239357` is equal to `0x6974733D`.

Tt seems that the last 4 bytes are used as the value because the multi-character character constant it too long to fit 32-bit integer.

The `0`, which is from `num`, is added, so the output became `17692393570`.